# Botón que muestra y oculta imágenes

Tags: javascript

estoy intentando hacer una galería sencilla en JS pero parece que no me funciona. Estoy haciendo lo siguiente:

html:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="menu-galeria">
            <button onclick="boton('todas')" class="btn btn-primary">Todas</button>
            <button onclick="boton('montaje')" class="btn btn-primary">Montajes</button>
            <button onclick="boton('escenario')" class="btn btn-primary">Escenarios</button>
            <button onclick="boton('dj')" class="btn btn-primary">Equipamiento DJ</button>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="row">
        <img class="todos montaje" src="img1.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="todos montaje" src="img2.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="todos montaje" src="img3.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="todos montaje" src="img4.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="todos montaje" src="img5.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="todos montaje" src="img6.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="todos montaje" src="img7.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="todos escenario" src="img8.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="todos escenario" src="img9.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="todos escenario" src="img10.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="todos escenario" src="img11.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="todos escenario" src="img12.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="todos dj" src="img13.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="todos dj" src="img14.jpg" alt="" >
        <img class="todos dj" src="img15.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="todos dj" src="img16.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
```

Código JS: ( Lo que intento hacer es que dependiendo del botón al que le den, muestre eso y oculte el resto, se que no será lo más eficiente que exista, pero quiero entender lo que estoy haciendo y el por qué de no funionar bien).

```
function boton(clase) {

    switch(clase) {
        case "todos":
            document.getElementsByClassName("montaje").style.display = "flex";
            document.getElementsByClassName("escenario").style.display = "flex";
            document.getElementsByClassName("dj").style.display = "flex";
            break;
        case "montaje":
            document.getElementsByClassName("montaje").style.display = "flex";
            document.getElementsByClassName("escenario").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementsByClassName("dj").style.display = "none";
            break;
        case "escenario":
            document.getElementsByClassName("montaje").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementsByClassName("escenario").style.display = "flex";
            document.getElementsByClassName("dj").style.display = "none";
            break;
        case "dj":
            document.getElementsByClassName("montaje").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementsByClassName("escenario").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementsByClassName("dj").style.display = "dj";
    } 
}
```

¿ Qué estoy haciendo mal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) devuelve un [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), es decir una *colección* de elementos, no *un* elemento. Con lo cual, no podes cambiarle el estilo directamente.

Lo que tenés que hacer es recorrer la colección y cambiarle el estilo a cada uno de los elementos. Para hacer eso podes utilizar [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

Por otro lado, tenés un error en el botón de `todos` tiene como parámetro `todas`.

```js
function boton(clase) {
  switch (clase) {
    case "todos":
      Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("montaje")).forEach(e => e.style.display = "flex");
      Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("escenario")).forEach(e => e.style.display = "flex");
      Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("dj")).forEach(e => e.style.display = "flex");
      break;

    case "montaje":
      Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("montaje")).forEach(e => e.style.display = "flex");
      Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("escenario")).forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
      Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("dj")).forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
      break;

    case "escenario":
      Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("montaje")).forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
      Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("escenario")).forEach(e => e.style.display = "flex");
      Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("dj")).forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
      break;

    case "dj":
      Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("montaje")).forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
      Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("escenario")).forEach(e => e.style.display = "none");
      Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("dj")).forEach(e => e.style.display = "flex");
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button onclick="boton('todos')" class="btn btn-primary">Todas</button>
  <button onclick="boton('montaje')" class="btn btn-primary">Animales</button>
  <button onclick="boton('escenario')" class="btn btn-primary">Comida</button>
  <button onclick="boton('dj')" class="btn btn-primary">Gente</button>
</div>

<img class="todos montaje" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-300-300-1.jpg" alt="">
<img class="todos montaje" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-300-300-2.jpg" alt="">
<img class="todos montaje" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-300-300-3.jpg" alt="">
<img class="todos escenario" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-300-300-1.jpg" alt="">
<img class="todos escenario" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-300-300-2.jpg" alt="">
<img class="todos escenario" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-300-300-3.jpg" alt="">
<img class="todos dj" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-300-300-1.jpg" alt="">
<img class="todos dj" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-300-300-2.jpg" alt="">
<img class="todos dj" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-300-300-3.jpg" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Spread_operator) para hacer que tus elementos seleccionados por clase sean iterables, luego usar una función que haga el trabajo.

```js
const $montajes = [...document.getElementsByClassName('montaje')]
const $escenarios = [...document.getElementsByClassName('escenario')]
const $djs = [...document.getElementsByClassName('dj')]

function boton(clase) {
  switch(clase) {
    case "todos":
      setVisibility($montajes, 'block')
      setVisibility($escenarios, 'block')
      setVisibility($djs, 'block')
      break;
    case "montaje":
      setVisibility($montajes, 'block')
      setVisibility($escenarios, 'none')
      setVisibility($djs, 'none')
      break;
    case "escenario":
      setVisibility($montajes, 'none')
      setVisibility($escenarios, 'block')
      setVisibility($djs, 'none')
      break;
    case "dj":
      setVisibility($montajes, 'none')
      setVisibility($escenarios, 'none')
      setVisibility($djs, 'block')
      break;
  }
}

function setVisibility(items, visible) {
  items.forEach(item => item.style.display = visible)
}
```

```css
.todos {
  margin: .5rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center my-4">
    <div class="menu-galeria">
      <button onclick="boton('todos')" class="btn btn-primary">Todas</button>
      <button onclick="boton('montaje')" class="btn btn-primary">Montajes</button>
      <button onclick="boton('escenario')" class="btn btn-primary">Escenarios</button>
      <button onclick="boton('dj')" class="btn btn-primary">Equipamiento DJ</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <img class="todos montaje" src="https://picsum.photos/40/40?random=1" alt="">
    <img class="todos montaje" src="https://picsum.photos/40/40?random=2" alt="">
    <img class="todos escenario" src="https://picsum.photos/40/40?random=3" alt="">
    <img class="todos escenario" src="https://picsum.photos/40/40?random=4" alt="">
    <img class="todos dj" src="https://picsum.photos/40/40?random=5" alt="">
    <img class="todos dj" src="https://picsum.photos/40/40?random=6" alt="" >
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

tu errror se da porque recibes una coleccion no un solo elemento lo mejor seria usar `querySelectorAll()`

puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
function recorrer(clase,disp){
  let elementos = document.querySelectorAll("."+clase);

  for(x of elementos){
    x.style.display = disp;
  }
}

function boton(clase) {

    switch(clase) {
        case "todos":
            // document.getElementsByClassName("montaje").style.display = "flex";
            // document.getElementsByClassName("escenario").style.display = "flex";
            // document.getElementsByClassName("dj").style.display = "flex";
            recorrer("montaje","flex");
            recorrer("escenario","flex");
            recorrer("dj","flex");
            break;
        case "montaje":
            // document.getElementsByClassName("montaje").style.display = "flex";
            // document.getElementsByClassName("escenario").style.display = "none";
            // document.getElementsByClassName("dj").style.display = "none";
            recorrer( "montaje","flex");
            recorrer("escenario","none");
            recorrer("dj","none");
            break;
        case "escenario":
            // document.getElementsByClassName("montaje").style.display = "none";
            // document.getElementsByClassName("escenario").style.display = "flex";
            // document.getElementsByClassName("dj").style.display = "none";
            recorrer( "montaje","none");
            recorrer("escenario","flex");
            recorrer("dj","none");
            break;
        case "dj":
            // document.getElementsByClassName("montaje").style.display = "none";
            // document.getElementsByClassName("escenario").style.display = "none";
            // document.getElementsByClassName("dj").style.display = "dj";
            recorrer( "montaje","none");
            recorrer("escenario","none");
            recorrer("dj","dj");
    } 
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="menu-galeria">
            <button onclick="boton('todos')" class="btn btn-primary">Todas</button>
            <button onclick="boton('montaje')" class="btn btn-primary">Montajes</button>
            <button onclick="boton('escenario')" class="btn btn-primary">Escenarios</button>
            <button onclick="boton('dj')" class="btn btn-primary">Equipamiento DJ</button>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="row">
        <img class="todos montaje" src="https://i.blogs.es/6c558d/luna-400mpx/1366_2000.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="todos montaje" src="https://i.blogs.es/6c558d/luna-400mpx/1366_2000.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="todos montaje" src="https://i.blogs.es/6c558d/luna-400mpx/1366_2000.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="todos montaje" src="https://i.blogs.es/6c558d/luna-400mpx/1366_2000.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="todos montaje" src="https://i.blogs.es/6c558d/luna-400mpx/1366_2000.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="todos montaje" src="https://i.blogs.es/6c558d/luna-400mpx/1366_2000.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="todos montaje" src="https://i.blogs.es/6c558d/luna-400mpx/1366_2000.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="todos escenario" src="https://i.blogs.es/6c558d/luna-400mpx/1366_2000.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="todos escenario" src="https://i.blogs.es/6c558d/luna-400mpx/1366_2000.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="todos escenario" src="https://i.blogs.es/6c558d/luna-400mpx/1366_2000.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="todos escenario" src="https://i.blogs.es/6c558d/luna-400mpx/1366_2000.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="todos escenario" src="https://i.blogs.es/6c558d/luna-400mpx/1366_2000.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="todos dj" src="https://i.blogs.es/6c558d/luna-400mpx/1366_2000.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="todos dj" src="https://i.blogs.es/6c558d/luna-400mpx/1366_2000.jpg" alt="" >
        <img class="todos dj" src="https://i.blogs.es/6c558d/luna-400mpx/1366_2000.jpg" alt="">
        <img class="todos dj" src="https://i.blogs.es/6c558d/luna-400mpx/1366_2000.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
```